# How do I put a MultiDatesPicker in Spanish?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core, razor, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

In the view of my Asp.Net App I have the following code at the end:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-ui-multidatespicker/1.6.6/jquery-ui.multidatespicker.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-ui-multidatespicker/1.6.6/jquery-ui.multidatespicker.css" />
<script>
    $('#mdp-demo').multiDatesPicker({
        dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
    });
</script>
```

That is the script which makes a MultiDatePicket appear in my view (https://dubrox.github.io/Multiple-Dates-Picker-for-jQuery-UI/)

And I call the MultiDatepicket in a Div like this:

```
  <div class="form-group">
      <input id="mdp-demo" autocomplete="off" name="selectedDates">
  </div>
```

Now my question is, how do I get the Calendar which is seen in the view to be a Spanish Calendar instead of the default English Calendar?

According to a tutorial I found, you can manually modify a normal DatePicket so the result in the view is a calendar in Spanish, with a code like this:

```
<script>
 $.datepicker.regional['es'] = {
 closeText: 'Cerrar',
 prevText: '< Ant',
 nextText: 'Sig >',
 currentText: 'Hoy',
 monthNames: ['Enero', 'Febrero', 'Marzo', 'Abril', 'Mayo', 'Junio', 'Julio', 'Agosto', 'Septiembre', 'Octubre', 'Noviembre', 'Diciembre'],
 monthNamesShort: ['Ene','Feb','Mar','Abr', 'May','Jun','Jul','Ago','Sep', 'Oct','Nov','Dic'],
 dayNames: ['Domingo', 'Lunes', 'Martes', 'Miércoles', 'Jueves', 'Viernes', 'Sábado'],
 dayNamesShort: ['Dom','Lun','Mar','Mié','Juv','Vie','Sáb'],
 dayNamesMin: ['Do','Lu','Ma','Mi','Ju','Vi','Sá'],
 weekHeader: 'Sm',
 dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
 firstDay: 1,
 isRTL: false,
 showMonthAfterYear: false,
 yearSuffix: ''
 };
 $.datepicker.setDefaults($.datepicker.regional['es']);
$(function () {
$("#fecha").datepicker();
});
</script>
```

But I can't find how to make this work for a MultiDatePicket, how can I do it? How do I include the code which modifies the name of the days/months in the MultiDatePitcket script to change the calendar to a Spanish Calendar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you setup your regional configuration before you call `$.fn.multiDatesPicker`.

The order your scripts load matters, because they load top-down.

```js
$.datepicker.regional['es'] = {
  closeText: 'Cerrar',
  prevText: '< Ant',
  nextText: 'Sig >',
  currentText: 'Hoy',
  monthNames: ['Enero', 'Febrero', 'Marzo', 'Abril', 'Mayo', 'Junio', 'Julio', 'Agosto', 'Septiembre', 'Octubre', 'Noviembre', 'Diciembre'],
  monthNamesShort: ['Ene', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Abr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Ago', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dic'],
  dayNames: ['Domingo', 'Lunes', 'Martes', 'Miércoles', 'Jueves', 'Viernes', 'Sábado'],
  dayNamesShort: ['Dom', 'Lun', 'Mar', 'Mié', 'Juv', 'Vie', 'Sáb'],
  dayNamesMin: ['Do', 'Lu', 'Ma', 'Mi', 'Ju', 'Vi', 'Sá'],
  weekHeader: 'Sm',
  dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
  firstDay: 1,
  isRTL: false,
  showMonthAfterYear: false,
  yearSuffix: ''
};

$.datepicker.setDefaults($.datepicker.regional['es']);

$('#mdp-demo').multiDatesPicker({ dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy", });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-ui-multidatespicker/1.6.6/jquery-ui.multidatespicker.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-ui-multidatespicker/1.6.6/jquery-ui.multidatespicker.css" />

<div class="form-group">
  <input id="mdp-demo" autocomplete="off" name="selectedDates">
</div>
```